# How do I make a disc image with all files and apps?

Tags: files, backup, usb-creator, disk-image

Ok, I wiped my HD, installed 12.04, installed all my apps, music, etc and have my OS exactly where I want it and would like to make an exact bootable image of everything to a 32G thumb drive so that I can install it to another HD and be up and running with all my stuff if anything ever happens to my current HD.
This is giving me problems.  I can't even find the ISO file much less anything else.

I would really appreciate a walk-through on this one.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd ?

Comment: [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page) solves the problem of saving a partition into a file and restoring from a file.

Comment: I use [deploystudio](http://www.deploystudio.com/Home.html) to make and boot from images over the network. I use it at work to image labs of computers but it is just as easy to use at home to make backup images that are easily booted to and restored from. The only problem is that it requires a mac server. Another option we have had success with is norton ghost, although this is not free. Clonezilla may also work for you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm an idiot but, I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I looked into the clonezilla option as I don't have a mac server and it talked about GNU/linux not ubuntu and, moreover, the instructions had me lost pretty quick.  Isn't there something out there that I can just download and click "create system image" after entering the destination?